# Use ManyToManyField as slug in url

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to have my url include the category and name of product. Rather than using `ForeignKey` to assign the category for a product I have chose `ManyToManyField` because some products belong in multiple categories. If I navigate to say `http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/shirts/tshirt/`. I get `Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'category'. Choices are: (none)`

I also get an error when I go to a category detail page such as `http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/shirts/`.

`Reverse for 'model_detail_view' with arguments '('', 'tshirt')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['products/(?P<category_slug>[^/]+)/(?P<model_slug>[^/]+)/$']`

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    model_slug = AutoSlugField(null=True, default=None,
                         unique=True, populate_from='title')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Products"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**views.py**

```
def model_category_detail_view(request, category_slug):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, category_slug=category_slug)
    context = {
        "products": Product.objects.filter(category__category_slug=category_slug),
    }
    return render(request=request,
                  template_name='main/category_detail.html', context=context)

def model_detail_view(request, category_slug, model_slug):
    products = Product.objects.select_related('category').get(
        category__category_slug=category_slug, model_slug=model_slug)
    context = {
        "products": products,
    }
    return render(request=request, template_name='main/model_detail.html', context=context)
```

**urls.py**

```
path("products/<str:category_slug>/<str:model_slug>/", views.model_detail_view, name="model_detail_view"),
```

**template**

```
{% for product in products %}
    <a class="btn btn-outline" href="{% url 'main:model_detail_view' product.category.category_slug product.model_slug %}"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>View Model</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `category` is a many to many field, you should pass it to `prefetch_related` instead

Comment: with m2m field you need to use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

Comment: Thank you. I can now directly visit a product page however if I go to a category detail page with hrefs to products I get an error. I updated my question to include more code